# Combine items after mapping from an array to a single object

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me to create object out of array of objects?

Array to convert arr = [{name:'Ryan'}, {surname:'raynold'}]

required output finalObj = {name:ryan, surname:raynold}

I tried to get the result by doing

let objectArr = Object.assign({}, arr);

but result was like this

{ 0: {shoulder: "14"}, 1:{neck: ""} }

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: the array has two element, need to combined them in a single object.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for `Object.assign`.

```js
let arr = [{name:'Ryan'}, {surname:'raynold'}]

let finalObj = Object.assign({}, ...arr);

console.log(finalObj);
```

`Object.assign` can take multiple objects as arguments, and so you can *spread* those objects from your input array. The first argument represents the object in which the others are merged.

Comment: Nice one!!! This really is a good case for Object.assign!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't spreading the arr thats why i wasn't getting the required result.

Comment: What if the second object has nested object ?
let arr = [ { name:'Ryan' } , { surname: {middleName: 'Robins' }, {lastName: 'Raynolds' } } ]

how do i  get an object of  {  name: 'Ryan'  ,  middleName: 'Robins' , lastName: 'Raynolds'  }

Comment: Then you must pick up the entries at the nested level (loop over them). If you cannot make it work, and cannot find a similar question, then feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a array reduce like this:

```
let finalObj = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc, ...cur}), {})
```

Comment: Thank you, @trincot answer did the trick, however i'll also try yours.